# How to get the value from html textbox and print it in terminal through a python script?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, cgi

I am working in a Linux VNC. It has an older python version 2.7 and so I couldn't use any of predefined GUI packages which are not available in this version. So I need an alternative to do that. Also with these below codes, the code is getting redirected to html page but at the same time the cgi script also runs and prints the output in the terminal as "None" value. So I want the html part to be done first and after giving the input in webpage and clicking the submit button, i must get that value in terminal. How can i do that?  Also cgi-bin folder is not there, so on clicking the submit button, getting a File Not Found error as well. Please help me through this...

**test.py**

```
import webbrowser

def func1():
    f = open('helloworld.html','w')

    message = """<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form name="get" action="/cgi-bin/cgi_test.py" method="get">
    Name : <input type="text" name="nm"/></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>"""

    f.write(message)
    f.close()

    webbrowser.open('helloworld.html')
```

**cgi_test.py**

```
import test
import cgi
test.func1()
form=cgi.FieldStorage()
n=form.getvalue('nm')
print (n)
```

Comment: better use flask module. you will have less work and problems.

Comment: to run it you need Web Server like Apache or Nginx which receives request for `cgi_test.py` page, executes it and sends result to browser. Better use flask which has build-in web server.

Comment: or find tutorial how to create in Python simple HTML server with CGI ie. [A Simple Python CGI Server Tutorial](https://pointlessprogramming.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/python-cgi-tutorial-1/)

Comment: Hi furas..Its a client's remote we are working with and we are not allowed to install any additional softwares or packages into it. Thats the problem now. So the job is to get it done with what we are provided with. Also after getting things on terminal, I need to change the code to execute 3 commands on shell as well. Lot of connections to b done but no proper S/Ws and packages.

Comment: Simple CGI server should be in standard library so you don't have to instal. Besides `Tkinter` GUI should be in standard library so you don't have to install too.

Comment: btw. [bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) web framework is in single file so you don't have to install - you can copy to your folder with project.